# Ubuntu 14.04.4 keeps logging me out

Tags: boot, unity, login, logout

I installed ubuntu 14.04.4 on my laptop last ight and it keeps logging me out. Its not my display setting i have it set to never turn the screen off. when it logs me out it closes all programs and turns off num lock its almost like its doing a reboot but not rebooting all the way. I think it might be an xorg issue but do not fully understand how to fix that.

I have tried changing my hardware acceleration from good to fast and it did not work so i tired switching it from fast to best and that still has not worked.

Memory 3.8 gb
processor: intel core i3-5020u
Graphics: intel HD Graphics 5500(broadwell GT2)
OS type 64-bit
disk 980.3 GB

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
```

dmesg| tail

```
[  463.283921] traps: compiz[2178] general protection ip:7f808536235c sp:7ffdf84a3570 error:0 in ld-2.19.so[7f808534f000+23000]
[  663.464382] traps: compiz[3194] general protection ip:7fd00761f35c sp:7ffce5a5fc10 error:0 in ld-2.19.so[7fd00760c000+23000]
[  959.854820] systemd-hostnamed[4443]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2671.419581] traps: compiz[4177] general protection ip:7fb4b4d7535c sp:7ffc94b9cc60 error:0 in ld-2.19.so[7fb4b4d62000+23000]
[ 2672.896054] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
[ 2906.746254] traps: compiz[5593] general protection ip:7fbb13eca35c sp:7ffdb5d2d7f0 error:0 in ld-2.19.so[7fbb13eb7000+23000]
[ 2906.785327] systemd-hostnamed[5942]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2931.320379] traps: compiz[6533] general protection ip:7f30c302035c sp:7ffdccd40fe0 error:0 in ld-2.19.so[7f30c300d000+23000]
[ 2932.490230] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
[ 2932.490411] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
```

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` before rebooting. Does the problem go away?

Comment: Also run `sudo apt-get install libnss-myhostname`.

Comment: it says permision denied when i tried add architecture i386 but the second one ran

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to put a `sudo` before it. Try it again.

Comment: ok it went through should i reboot?

Comment: Yes, Try a reboot and see how it goes.

Comment: it is still logging me off... I dont get it i have been trying to fix this all day

Comment: I do notice that you pasted the contents of the old Xorg log file and not the current one.

Comment: ok i replaced it with the current one

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/274320

Comment: I tried this and it is still logging me out. do you think if i installed ubuntu 15.10 it would help? what i dont get is why it does this when it is a fresh installed i have reinstalled it 3 times now and everytime it has the same problem. and it is so random i will be using it then it will log me out. everything i have found similiar is people log in then almost immediatly it logs them back out...could it be a graphics error?

Comment: also if i just leave the laptop sit it does not do this it only happens while i am actively using it

Comment: It might be a graphics issue, but I'm not too sure. When you reinstalled, did you use the same installation medium as before? It's possible either the ISO file you downloaded or the disc/USB is corrupt. Also, did you use a DVD or USB stick, and what did you use to burn Ubuntu to it?

Comment: well on this installation is the first for ubuntu on my laptop i just removed windows 10(thank god). I used a disc and I dont think it would be corrupt because it is the same disk i used to install ubuntu on my desktop months ago and my desk top has always ran fine never had any issues. i am pretty sure i used imgburn in windows originally to burn the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing ubuntu 14.04 and installing elementary OS. I was kind of iffy about it at first but wow elementary is a great OS very solid so far have had no issues.